# Error message: Symbol's value as variable is void: erg when using ipython with python-mode

Tags: emacs, ipython, python-mode

In my case, I got the error upon entering the first line into an ipython buffer. This appears to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/921364) in python-mode 6.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to edit lines 1565-1566 of python-mode.el like so.

```
(let ((lastindent (if
                         (py-beginning-of-statement-p)
                         (current-indentation)
                       (progn
-                   (py-down-statement)
-                   (current-indentation)))))
+                   (py-down-statement)
+                   (current-indentation))))
+     erg)
```

Also, this is fixed in 6.0.5

Answer (score 0):

this bug should not occur in current trunk resp. latest release

http://launchpad.net/python-mode